# Powershell dynamic array with multiple columns

Tags: arrays, powershell, dynamic

Not very well versed with arrays, so I would kindly ask for some assistance.

I'm trying to get three columns into an array utilizing the Read-Host and Get Credential cmdlets.
The array needs to be dynamic so that when the user starts the script, it asks for the URL, then its Username and then its password, and loops this to add several more rows (servers) until the URL input is empty.

Then I would end with an array like this:

```
Server Username Password
------ -------- --------
data1  data2    data3
```

So I have this:

```
$array = @()
do {
    $URI = Read-Host "Enter server URI"
    

    if ($URI -ne '') {
        $Username = Read-Host "Enter server URI"
        $credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter credentials for $URI" -UserName $Username
        $Password = $credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString
    
    
        $item = New-Object PSObject
        $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Server' -Value $URI
        $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Username' -Value $Username
        $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Password' -Value $Password

    $array += $item}
 
}
until ($URI -eq '')

$array
```

Obviously this isn't working cause the output and error I get are:

```
Enter server URI: http://server/module
Enter server URI:
Get-Credential: 
Line |
   8 |  … -Credential -Message "Enter credentials for $URI" -UserName $Username
     |                                                                ~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot validate argument on parameter 'UserName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
ConvertFrom-SecureString: 
Line |
   9 |          $Password = $credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString
     |                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'SecureString' because it is null.
```

Comment: `$Username = Read-Host "Enter server URI"` is misleading, since you want someone to fill in a user name while you are asking for the URI a second time. Your own output shows you don't fill this in yourself too, so `$Username` remains empty and hence the error